# Text not Setting in JTextArea/Field

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, jtextarea

I am having problems setting some text in a JTextArea and a JTextField...I am a little confused because I have set text in them before, as a matter of fact I have set them in a different class of this same program without any problems... I have printed out the String to check to make sure that it isn't null or just empty "" and my strings do print what they are supposed to but they don't set in the JTextField/Area..

Can anyone tell me why it is messing up?

(I have given you the whole code so that you are not confused by a method call but most of it is probably not necessary. All you really should need to focus on is the run() method and the populateInfo() method. populateInfo() is where it should be setting the test to the textArea and textField.)

Below is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EditDiary extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

  private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  private String[] date;
  private String[] rest;
  private int index = 0;
  private int count = 0;

  private JLabel lblDate = new JLabel("Date");
  private JTextField txtDate = new JTextField();
  private JLabel lblDiary = new JLabel("Diary Entry");
  private JTextArea txtDiary = new JTextArea(20,30);

  private JButton btnDone = new JButton("Done");
  private JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

  public EditDiary(){

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

    panel1.add(lblDate);
    panel1.add(txtDate);
    panel1.add(lblDiary);
    panel1.add(txtDiary);
    panel1.add(btnDone);
    panel1.add(btnCancel);

    add(panel1);

    btnDone.addActionListener(this);
    btnCancel.addActionListener(this);

  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == btnDone) {

      try {
        editInfo();
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {

      }
      finally {

      }
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == btnCancel) {
      // Haven't done anything here yet
    }
  }

  public void run(String[] sDate, String[] sRest, int iIndex, int iCount) {

    date = sDate;
    rest = sRest;
    index = iIndex;
    count = iCount;

    JApplet applet = new EditDiary();
    frame.add(applet);
    frame.setTitle("Edit Diary Entry");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1280, 800);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);

    populateInfo();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }

  public void populateInfo() {

    // System.out.println(date[index]);
    // System.out.println(rest[index]);

    txtDate.setText(date[index]);
    txtDiary.setText(rest[index]);

  }

  public void editInfo() throws Exception {

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Diary.txt"));

    date[index] = txtDate.getText();
    rest[index] = txtDiary.getText();

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      out.write(date[i]);
      out.write(rest[i]);
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that calls `run()`? Why do you have a `main()` that doesn't do anything? Why do you have a finally that doesn't do anything?

Comment: The code that calls run is of no concern...all that you need to know is that it does get called and that it does read in the arrays and what not...I have no concern to anything you have said here, i am not done with the rest of the code...I just need to know why the textArea/Field is not populating

Answer (score 3):

> The code that calls run is of no concern...

When you have a problem, you don't know what code is or isn't relevant. The context of how code is invoked is relevant. What makes you think we can always solve problems just by looking at the code. Sometimes we actually need to execute the code so we can see the actual logic flow of the program etc.

This is not how you create an Applet. Components should be added to the applet in the init() method of the applet. I suggest you read [How to Make Applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html).

The problem with your code is that you have 2 instances of the EditDiary class. One that is the Applet and one that you attempt to add to the frame. However the ActionListener code only references the Applet text components, not the components added to the frame.

You need a redesign of your program. Maybe the code to create the frame should be an inner class so that you can create variables and listeners that belong to the frame and not the applet.